# material-ui table clear selection

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I am working with material-table in reactjs and wanted to know if it is possible to clear my selection after I do a update or have another button to clear my selection. I did read through the documentation but never find anything that could help

[image]

Code:

```
          <MaterialTable
              title="User data from remote source"
              columns ={[
                {title: "id", field: "id", hidden: true},
                {title: "Avatar", render: rowData => <Avatar maxInitials={1} size={40} round={true} name={rowData === undefined ? " " : rowData.first_name} />  },
                {title: "First name", field: "first_name", },
                {title: "Last name", field: "last_name"},
                {title: "email", field: "email"}
              ]}

              data={data}
              icons={tableIcons}
              options={{
                actionsColumnIndex: -1,
                headerStyle: {
                  backgroundColor: 'lightgray',
                  color: 'black'
                },
                selection: true
              }}
            />
```

Answer (score 2):

From what I see the selection data is hidden within the `<MaterialTable/>`.
There's a topic [here](https://github.com/mbrn/material-table/issues/153) suggesting to place a ref that would help with clearing or update the component.

A quick hack that comes to my mind is trying to force an update by taking advantage of `key` prop.

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
    const [ resetKey, setResetKey ] = useState(0);

    const forceReset = () => {
        setResetKey(resetKey++);
    };

    return (
        <>
            <MaterialTable key={`MaterialTable-${resetKey}`} {...materialTableProps} />
            <button onClick={forceReset}>RESET</button>
        </>
    );
}
```

But I can't really guarantee that it'll work - if so, the solution with using a ref would be your last resort, which probably should look something like this:

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
    const tableRef = useRef(null);

    const forceReset = () => {
        tableRef.current.onAllSelected(false);
    };

    return (
        <>
            <MaterialTable tableRef={tableRef} {...materialTableProps}/>
            <button onClick={forceReset}>RESET</button>
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: The second strategy `onAllSelected(false)` just worked for me.